# Problema phpmailer al agregar adjunto

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de enviar correos desde codeigniter, utilizo la librería phpmailer, mi problema radica en que cuando agrego un adjunto al objeto de la clase, al parecer este se limpia, no entiendo el por qué.

Este el código que utilizo para hacer el envío y cargue del adjunto

```html
<?php 

                                $objMailer = new PHPMailer(true);
    $objMailer->isSMTP();
    $objMailer->Host = 'localhost';
    $objMailer->Port = '25';
    $objMailer->ClearAddresses();
    $titulo = $val['name_email'];
    
    // $objMailer->setFrom($data['emails'][$i]['email_from'], $titulo);
    $objMailer->setFrom('cristian.higuita@gmail.com', $titulo);
    
    $objMailer->AddAddress($val['email_to']);
    $objMailer->IsHTML(true);
    $objMailer->Subject = $titulo;
    $objMailer->Body = 'prueba';
    
    $location = "upload/" . $val['path'] . '/' . $val['attached_id'];
    $objMailer->AddAttachment($location, $val['filename'], $val['file_mime_type']);
    
    $bool = $objMailer->Send();


?>
```

Agradecería una mano, gracias

Comment: Nota: si yo hago un print de la información antes de cargar el adjunto puedo verla en pantalla, sin embargo si lo hago luego de agregar el adjunto, esta desaparece.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar mi error, en el servidor se almacenan los archivos sin extensión y al tratar de cargarlo en la función AddAttachment() de la librería phpMailer validan que el path dentro del método is_file(), esto me salta a la excepción ya que en el servidor no se almacena la extensión. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo obtener el archivo del servidor?